# Qt: How to fix deployment of Nokia Smart Installer?

Tags: qt, deployment, uid

I'm developing a Qt application using the Qt Nokia SDK (Yes i know i can use the Qt SDK version 1.1.1, but i don't want to that right now because of tight schedule).

The application is finished and i have applied for UID's from OVI and received UID's, cert installer and developer cert/key pair for testing.

-I received these UID's:

```
UID# 0x200XXXX1
UID# 0x200XXXX2
UID# 0x200XXXX3
UID# 0x200XXXX4
UID# 0x200XXXX5
```

-I installed the cert installer on the test device

- Changed the build settings so that i use the certificate i received from OVI:[image: Build Settings]
- Changed the project file so that it takes use of the UID (This is a part of the .pro file)(See UID's):

  ```
  VERSION = 1.0.0
  DEPLOYMENT.display_name=Project
  DEPLOYMENT.installer_header = "$${LITERAL_HASH}{\"Project App Installer \"}, {0x2002CCCF}, 1,0,0"

  symbian {
  TARGET.UID3 = 0x200XXXX1
  TARGET.CAPABILITY += NetworkServices \
                       ReadUserData \
                       WriteUserData \
                       ReadDeviceData \
                       WriteDeviceData
  ICON = Icon-no-glare-tiny1.2.svg
  TARGET.EPOCSTACKSIZE = 0x14000
  TARGET.EPOCHEAPSIZE = 0x020000 0x800000
  INCLUDEPATH += C:/NokiaQtSDK/Symbian/SDK/epoc32/include
  LIBS += -LC:/NokiaQtSDK/Symbian/SDK_OK/epoc32/release/armv5/lib
  LIBS += -lcone \
  -leikcore \
  -lavkon \
  -letel3rdparty
  ```

  }
- **Problem:**
  By doing this i wrap the application using the Nokia smart installer (Which is something i want), but when i try to install this on my test device i get the message ***"Unable to install a protected application from an untrusted supplier"***

This happens only seconds after starting the installer, so i think it might be something wrong with the uid and Nokia smart installer.

- **Here's some candy though:**
  If i do not wrap the application using Nokia smart installer, i have no problems installing the application.

Does anyone have a suggestion i can try? i'm desperate in getting this working now.

If any questions, please do not hesitate to ask.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sign your application with the ovi developer cert and change UID to a supplied protected UID, only symbian signing your application will let you install it on a device. The developer certificates are provided only to allow your app to access restricted capabilities like redadevicedata writedevicedata etc.

tl;dr use unprotected uid to test , change to ovi supplied uid to publish.

Comment: But will my app be allowed to access restricted capabilities using an unprotected uid?

Comment: from what i remember it should . Why don't you try ?

Comment: Will try that tomorrow, thanks for the suggestion and explanation.

Comment: Ah, both using a test UID and removing the application and application installer from the device worked. Thanks!